# Angular2 SVG filter url

Tags: d3.js, svg, angular

I'm using Angular2 + D3 to create a chart.
I'd like to apply an svg filter to the bars in order to create a drop-shadow effect.
While the filter is created and the bars have a `filter: url("#dropshadow")` style applied, the shadow does not render.
Could this be due to Angulars single page and the `url()` not finding the filter? What would be the correct way to work around this issue?

Comment: Please show the code. Have you tried the same outside the Angular2 application? How did you set the `<base href="...">` and `APP_BASE_HREF`?

Comment: `<head><base href="/"> ... </head>` in `index.html`. I haven't set APP_BASE_HREF, should I? It does work outside of angular... Code is a bit too big to post right now, if I can't find a solution I'll create a smaller example reproducing the problem...

Comment: I have seen it mentioned that `<base href="...">` can break SVG. Try setting (providing) `APP_BASE_HREF` instead to configure the router. If it is for the router then you can provide `APP_BASE_HREF` and omit the base tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The best solution seems to be to inject the Location via

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(private location: Location)
```

and then use it to specify the path for the `url()`

```
.style('filter', 'url(' + this.location.path() + '#drop-shadow)')
```

Now it works as expected.

Comment: Spent a couple hours bashing my head against the wall trying to fix this problem before I eventually traced the problem to ng2 router and SVG filters conflicting.  Eventually found this and now it works perfectly.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In case some one arrives here and this isn't clear enough here is what i did for any `url` used in `<svg>` with Safari:

In my components i import Location

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

...
  constructor(private location: Location) {
  }

  url(id: string) {
    return `url(${this.location.path()}${id}`;
  }

}
```

Then use it in the inline `<svg>` tags as follows

```
[attr.filter]="url('#filter-11')"

[attr.clip-path]="url('#clip')"
```