# SVG filter url is not working in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

Hi I am drawing a line using SVG in Angular and i am using some filters for glow effects, but the filter url is not working in the browser and it is not displaying anything when i am doing "ng serve". but the same svg is working fine in the stand-alone svg file.

```
<svg height="300" width="824">
    <g class="svgWrapper" transform="translate(412,150)">
        <defs>
            <filter id="glow">
                <fegaussianblur class="blur" result="coloredBlur" stddeviation="4"></fegaussianblur>
                <femerge>
                    <femergenode in="coloredBlur"></femergenode>
          <femergenode in="coloredBlur"></femergenode>
          <femergenode in="coloredBlur"></femergenode>
                    <femergenode in="SourceGraphic"></femergenode>
                </femerge>
            </filter>
        </defs>
     <path class="exampleGlow" d="M100,250 C100,100 400,100 400,250" style="fill-opacity: 0; stroke-width: 2; stroke: red; filter: url(#glow);" transform="translate(-250,-200)"/></path>
    </g></svg>
```

https://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/dRoQdN

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345823/angular2-svg-filter-url

Answer (score 0):

Seems like angular adds tag like `<base href="/dist/">` and safari or firefox can't resolve url. To fix it, you should prepend filter id's url by your current location:
`filter: url({{window.location.href}}#glow)`.