# Why is <feDropShadow> not displaying?

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, svg-filters

**Edit**: trying to create a [mcve](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-northcutt-h5lvf?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) I wasn't able to repro the issue. Now I'm completely baffled. Works on codesandbox, not in my project.

---

**Initial question**
I want to create a dynamic inline SVG element and map its rotation to an `[(ngModel)]`. Nothing fancy.

The fancy part is that I want to use a `<filter>` with a `<feDropShadow>`. And I want the shadow to be dynamic (always point up, regardless of the needle's rotation). It's something I've done before using Vue.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the effect: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/y4ghan0k/

But, for the life of me, I can't get the `<feDropShadow>` to work in Angular when the `<svg>` is inlined in the template. It just won't display. No error or warning. If I insert it as `<img src="path/to/svg">` it works as expected (the shadow is displayed), but then I can't rotate the path anymore, as the element transformed needs to be a child of the element bearing the filter.

Note it's not because of [this url() filter issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345823/angular2-svg-filter-url) - I am prefixing the filter with `this.location.path()`.

Here's the gist of my Angular code:

**component.ts:**

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private location: Location) {}
  dsLink = `url(${this.location.path()}#drop-shadow)`;
}
```

**component.html:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="180" y="100"
     viewBox="0 0 180 100" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <filter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="drop-shadow" height="130%">
      <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="-4" flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,.65)"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g [attr.filter]="dsLink">
    <path fill="#fff" d="M102.2,89.5c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6L92.9,6.8c-0.1-0.8-3.2-0.9-3.3,0
      L78.7,88.5c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6c0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2l0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.5,2.4,5.6,4.4,11.7,4.4
      c6.2,0.1,11.2-1.8,11.8-4.2c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1L102.2,89.5z">
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

For simplicity, I've removed the `[(ngModel)]` from path which is supposed to rotate the needle.

The filter `url()` appears to be correct, there's no error. But the shadow is not displayed.

Is there anything special I need to do/know in order to make Angular handle `<svg>` elements inline?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally cracked it so I'm posting it here, hoping it will help others.

In short: **use unique ids** for filters in each of your component instances. Otherwise, each instance will use the first filter found in DOM (with that id) and if that filter happens to be inside a parent with `display: none`, `visibility:hidden` or `opacity: 0`, applying the filter will make whatever you apply it to invisible as well.

---

The issue had to do with the fact I was using the same component in different tabs. This created separate instances of the component, each of them using the same id (`#drop-shadow`). While having duplicate ids is obviously invalid HTML, this wouldn't actually have been a problem if we weren't dealing with filters. Because, since the `<defs>` are identical, it wouldn't really matter if the component on the 4th tab would use the `<defs>` defined by the component on the first tab.

Except when dealing with `<filter>`s, because they are actually calculating, pixel by pixel, the rendering result, dynamically. Which means that, when the `<svg>` defining the `<filter>` is not rendered, using the filter will make the browser calculate (pixel by pixel) the result applying the filter and it always result in all the pixels being invisible.

So **the solution** is to assign a unique id in each separate instance of the component.